# How to get Datatable or Dataset into a Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

How would you go with getting the Datatable or the Dataset into a Session ? When the client connects to the app I want the client to hold the same session with the gridview for 30 min before timing out. How would you go about it? I have looked at a few examples 
at [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp) and [asp.net-Tutorials](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/)

But I just cant get started, im not sure to Session the DataTable or DataSet for one. This is the first time I am using Session with ASP.Net - Any feedback or tips is really appreciated!

```
using System;
using DBComponentsLibrary;
using DBComponentsLibrary.NameDataSetTableAdapters;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Name
{
    public partial class TestWebFormView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                DataBind();
                loadGridData();
        }
        private void loadGridData()
        {
            NameTableAdapter TA = new NameTableAdapter();
            NameDataSet rds = new NameDataSet();
            NameDataSet.NameDataTable Rdt = new NameDataSet.NameDataTable();
            TA.Fill(Rdt);
            GridView.DataSource = Rdt;
            GridView.DataBind();
            GridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Visible = true;
        }
        protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridView.DataBind();
        }
        protected void btnLastPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (GridView.PageCount > 0)
            {
                GridView.SetPageIndex(GridView.PageCount - 1);
            }
        }
        protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Will be implemented soon.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears that you are really asking  2 or 3 separate questions.
1. getting a session variable to hold a dataset?
2. Session Time Out.
3. Login time out?
Please show an example of your grid and what you are trying to accomplish?
I think Ican help you but I am not totally clear on what your end intention is?

Comment: @DaniDev Added backend code end intention is so a client logs into web app with windows auth and load the grid once instead of every time a function is used. (Should hopefully help a lot with performance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web.config set the session timeout for 30 minutes

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <sessionState mode="InProc"
                cookieless="false"
                timeout="30"/>
  </sessionState>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

In your application

```
if(Session["YourDataSet"] == null)
    Session["YourDataSet"] = GetDataSetFromSomeWhere();

YourGridView.DataSource = (DataSet)Session["YourDataSet"];
YourGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for to get started, accepted as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the code ,hope it will give you a start:

```
        if (Session["SeesionName"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["SeesionName"];
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["SNO"] = dt.Rows.Count + 1;
            row["EmpId"] = empId;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            gdSource.DataSource = dt;
            gdSource.DataBind();
            Session["SeesionName"] = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("SNO", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("EmpId", typeof(int));
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["EmpId"] = empId;
            row["SNO"] = 1;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            gdSource.DataSource = dt;
            gdSource.DataBind();
            Session["SeesionName"] = dt;
        }
```

Comment: Helped towards solution as well